# Java: incrementally shifting elements in a 2D array to the right

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to shift elements in a 2D array (specifically a square matrix) so that the result is a "staircase" pattern:

Original:

```
 1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

Objective:

```
 1  2  3  4  5
10  6  7  8  9
14 15 11 12 13
18 19 20 16 17
22 23 24 25 21
```

I've managed to write a program that can perform the task in a 1D array for the first line of the matrix (*see below*), but I can't seem to translate the code so that it functions in a 2D array.

- How do I get my code to function in a 2D array in Java?
- And, for later, how would I go about incrementing the change so that, as the row increases (from upper to lower levels of the matrix), the number of shifts also increases?

```js
public class StaircaseMatrix
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] num = {1,2,3,4,5};

        shiftRight(num);

        System.out.println("After shifting the array is:");
        for (int x = 0; x < num.length; x++)
            System.out.print(num[x] + " ");
    }


    public static void shiftRight(int[] list)
    {
        int last = list[list.length - 1];
        for (int j = list.length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
            list[j] = list[j - 1];
        }
        list[0] = last;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `shiftRight()` 0 times for `array2D[0]`, 1 time for `array2D[1]`, 2 times for `array2D[2]`, and so on, using a `for` loop.